# SQL group by that combines the 2nd group and get distinct first group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

The query currently returns

```
Bob    President     5
Joe    Programmer    3
Greg   Programmer    2
Joe    Janitor       6
Liz    Programmer    6
```

But I want it to only have one row for each person like this

```
Bob    President     5
Joe    Programmer (or Janitor)  9
Greg   Programmer    2
Liz    Programmer    6
```

I am grouping by the Name and the Role now. How to I also get only distinct names and combine that value ?

```
SELECT
   ...
FROM 
    vw_QuickbaseAudit v
    INNER JOIN [staging].[QuickbaseSystemUsers] qsu ON v.[user] = qsu.UserId
WHERE 
    Date_Modified >= @StartDate
    AND Date_Modified < DATEADD(dd, 1, @EndDate)
GROUP BY
    qsu.UserFirstName + ' ' + qsu.UserLastName, 
    qsu.RoleName
ORDER BY 
    RoleName, 
    NumberOfEditTotal DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreted this:

```
Joe    Programmer (or Janitor)  9
```

As saying that either of these is okay:

```
Joe    Programmer  9
Joe    Janitor     9
```

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT qsu.UserFirstName + ' ' + qsu.UserLastName, 
       MIN(qsu.RoleName) as RoleName
       SUM(NumberOfEditTotal) as NumberOfEditTotal
FROM vw_QuickbaseAudit v JOIN
     [staging].[QuickbaseSystemUsers] qsu 
     ON v.[user] = qsu.UserId
WHERE Date_Modified >= @StartDate AND
      Date_Modified < DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate)
GROUP BY qsu.UserFirstName + ' ' + qsu.UserLastName
ORDER BY RoleName, NumberOfEditTotal DESC;
```

It is unclear how `NumberOfEditTotal` is calculated.

EDIT:

Appending all the rows in tricky.  In the latest versions of SQL Server, you can use `STRING_AGG()` as a string aggregation functions.  That is simple.

My recommendation in early versions would be a compromise.  So values might be:

```
Janitor
Janitor and Programmer 
Janitor, Programmer, and others
```

You can do this with:

```
(case when min(rolename) = max(rolename)
      then min(rolename)
      when count(distinct rolename) = 2
      then min(rolename) + ' and ' + max(rolename)
      else min(rolename) + ', ' + max(rolename) + ' others'
 end)
```

Comment: got this working. But would be nice to append all the roles on one row

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT qsu.UserFirstName + ' ' + qsu.UserLastName AS "FullName",
    STUFF((SELECT '/' + r.RoleName FROM QuickbaseSystemUsers r on r.UserID = qsu.UserID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as "Roles",
    NumberOfEditTotal << [however you calced this]
FROM vw_QuickbaseAudit v
    INNER JOIN [staging].[QuickbaseSystemUsers] qsu ON v.[user] = qsu.UserId 
WHERE Date_Modified >= @StartDate AND Date_Modified < DATEADD(dd, 1, @EndDate) 
GROUP BY qsu.UserFirstName + ' ' + qsu.UserLastName, 
    STUFF((SELECT '/' + r.RoleName FROM QuickbaseSystemUsers r on r.UserID = qsu.UserID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
ORDER BY RoleName, NumberOfEditTotal DESC;
```

Some variant of that
(edited: missed the additional STUFF command in the group by)

Comment: I can't get the syntax right  
SELECT qsu.UserFirstName + ' ' + qsu.UserLastName AS FullName,
 --MIN(qsu.RoleName) as RoleName
     STUFF((SELECT '/' + r.RoleName FROM [staging].[QuickbaseSystemUsers] r on r.UserID = qsu.UserID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as Roles,

FROM vw_QuickbaseAudit v
     INNER JOIN [staging].[QuickbaseSystemUsers] qsu ON v.[user] = qsu.UserId
  GROUP BY qsu.UserFirstName + ' ' + qsu.UserLastName
ORDER BY RoleName

Comment: Sorry - I edited the sql, I accidentally skipped putting the STUFF command in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to remove  `RoleName` from the `GROUP BY` clause. You can do string aggregation with `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT
   qsu.UserFirstName + ' ' + qsu.UserLastName,
   STRING_AGG(RoleName, ' or ') RoleNames,
   ...
FROM 
    vw_QuickbaseAudit v
    INNER JOIN [staging].[QuickbaseSystemUsers] qsu ON v.[user] = qsu.UserId
WHERE 
    Date_Modified >= @StartDate
    AND Date_Modified < DATEADD(dd, 1, @EndDate)
GROUP BY
    qsu.UserFirstName,
    qsu.UserLastName
ORDER BY 
    NumberOfEditTotal DESC;
```

Comment: Nice. I was wondering what the equivalent was of PL/SQL's `listagg` in T-SQL. Need to add this to my notes.

Comment: @alans : I just changed my answer for a simpler version (still using `STRING_AGG()`. FYI `STRING_AGG()` is available starting SQLServer 2017.

Comment: I noticed. That explains why I haven't seen it before. Good to know.

Comment: Maybe its good. But doesnt work for my version of sql server 12.0.4439.1

Comment: @punkouter2018 : ok then I believe that you should have to look at the solution provided by MusicalCoder : `STUFF` has a more complex syntax, but it works on earlier versions of SqlServer.